# Pig script sum within a bag

Tags: apache-pig

Sum up the number of doubles and triples for each birthCity/birthState combination. Output the top 5 birthCity/birthState combinations that produced the players who had the most doubles and triples.

Currently I have this

```
clean = FOREACH filtered_2 GENERATE id,city,state, dble + tripple AS combined;
dump clean;
```

My questions is how do I fit the above? it's obvious I have to group by (city,state). how do I get sum within a bag if I do group by

[image]

```
 counter = foreach clean {
    sum1 = SUM(combined);
    generate id,city,state,sum1;
 };
```

I was thinking something like this but, it's not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group the relation clean by city,state and then use the SUM to get the total of the grouping for each city,state.

```
clean = FOREACH filtered_2 GENERATE id,city,state,(dble + tripple) AS combined;
clean_group = GROUP clean BY (city,state);
counter = FOREACH clean_group GENERATE FLATTEN(group) as (city,state),SUM(clean.combined) as sum1;
```

Comment: can u explain the last line? plz i am confused on how flatten works in this particular function

Comment: Since the grouping is by 2 fields, the group by 2 fields results in a tuple.So to extract the fields out of tuple you will have to use FLATTEN